# Remove a word from unknown length of string SWIFT

Tags: swift, swift3

I am trying to remove a word from unknown lengh of a string, here is my code.

```
if (newService.range(of: serviceStr) != nil){

    // I should remove selected word here

    print("remove selected")
}else{
    print("add select")
    let space = " , "
    newService = newService + space + serviceStr            
}
```

I have tried many ways, however, every code I should specify the offsetBy which I dont know because its user buttons selection.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can write

```
import Foundation

var sentence = "This is a simple sentence"
let wordToRemove = "simple"


if let range = sentence.range(of: wordToRemove) {
   sentence.removeSubrange(range)
}

print(sentence) // This is a  sentence
```

> If you also want to remove the additional space after the simple word replace this
>
> ```
> let wordToRemove = "simple"
> ```
>
> with this
>
> ```
> let wordToRemove = "simple "
> ```

Comment: AWESOME! IT WORKED!

Comment: What if you wanted to remove a list of words from the string? I attempted to make an array but got  the `String does not conform to expected type` error.

Answer (score 0):

This will do if you only need to remove `serviceStr`:

```
if let range = newService.range(of: serviceStr) {
    print("remove selected")
    newService.removeSubrange(range)
} else {
    print("add select")
    newService += " , " + serviceStr            
}
```

But if you need to add or remove a separator, it's more tricky, especially the way you wrote it: by always concatenating a comma, don't you end up with your first service also starting with an initial comma at the beginning of the string?

Here is a suggestion to get clean comma support:

```
let space = " , "
if let range = newService.range(of: serviceStr) {
    print("remove selected")
    newService.removeSubrange(range)
    newService = newService.components(separatedBy: space).filter({ !$0.isEmpty }).joined(separator: space)
} else {
    print("add select")
    var components = newService.components(separatedBy: space)
    components.append(serviceStr)
    newService = components.joined(separator: space)           
}
```